# How to set custom the global 'node_modules' location

Tags: node.js, npm

I have nodejs by path '/opt/nodejs/{version}' and property 'prefix' is '/opt/nodejs/{version}' but npm still installs packages into '/usr/lib/node_modules'.

Comment: have you confirmed your `prefix` is set correctly with `npm get prefix`?

Comment: @schu34, sure, he is '/opt/nodejs/{version}'